Conjectures on Smith Normal Form for Jucys-Murphy elements (Stanley, Grinberg) - status and generalisations?
There is an excellent review by R.Stanley "Smith Normal Form in Combinatorics" from 2016. At the very last page - certain conjectures on SMF (Smith Normal Form) of Jucys–Murphy elements are proposed based on computations by Darij Grinberg.
Question 1: Is there any progress on these conjectures ?
A part of the interest in Smith Normal Form recent years is due to its relation to the "Jacobian/Sanpile/Critical group" of a graph (e.g. section 3 in survey above). Which might be thought as "tropical degeneration" of Jacobian of the algebraic curve , when curve degenerates to graph. (See e.g. "search sandpile" on Mathoverflow). Computations of the Jacobian/Sandpile group is quite a difficult task for many graphs and it is widely unknown.
Question 2: Are there any graphs such that their Laplacian matrix might be somehow related to Jucys-Murphy elements ?
The story of Jucys-Murphy elements became popular after the work of A.Vershik and A.Okounkov who used them to develop: "A new approach to representation theory of symmetric groups", which is "new, simple and direct".  Since that time it was generalized in various directions. One of them is generalisation to Hecke algebra which q-deformation of $C[S_n]$ and basically one substitutes integers in Young tableaux by q-integer numbers.
Question 3: Is there any discussion on q-analogs (Hecke algebras) of the conjectures above or some other generalisations ?
Jucys-Murphy elements can be thought as a limit for very famous commuting family of operators: $H_i = \sum_{k\ne i} \sum_{j} (i,k)/(z_i-z_k) $ and $z_i$ are parameters. It is related to different names: Gaudin system, Garnier, Hitchin, Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov, polynomial matrices, so on. In appropriate limit of $z_i$ one gets Jucys-Murphy. (Relation was observed in our paper).
One may consider many other similar limits - they parametrized by binary trees or triangulatios of n-gon (similar to Catalan story). So these are in a sense boundary of moduli space of points $z_i$. Very nice way to look  - is "bending flows" due to Kapovich and Millson - for every triangulation of n-gon one has flows which bend n-gon via the diagonal - so each diagonal defines "Jucys-Murphy" element (they commute up to common rotation of 3d-space).
Question 4: Have these generalized Jucys-Murphy/bending flows elements were considered for computations of their SMF ?
In the same paper we also discussed the relation to Gelfand-Tsetlin elements - which can be related by GL(n)/GL(m) duality to Jucys-Murphy elements.
Question 5: Is there any generalisation of SMF conjectures to Gelfand-Tsetlin elements ?

Note about Question 1: The $W_{\lambda,k}$ in §7 of Stanley's paper is defined somewhat clumsily. It should be defined as the matrix representing the action of the YJM element $X_k$ on the Specht module $\mathcal{S}^\lambda$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the standard tableau basis. You can, of course, take any other basis, since the Smith normal form is conjugation-invariant. But the direct sum $\bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash n} f^\lambda W^{\lambda,k}$ is not the action of $X_k$ on the group ring of $S_n$, so you cannot define it through this sum.

And yes, I'm still interested in Question 1. To me, the most natural question here is actually finding a good basis of the GT subalgebra of $\mathbb{Z}\left[S_n\right]$ (that is, the $\mathbb{Z}$-subalgebra generated by $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$). Is this subalgebra a direct addend of $\mathbb{Z}\left[S_n\right]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module? It is ridiculous that we don't know the answer!
